# ClickListener Cannot be Resolved to a Type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having this error in Eclipse: `ClickListener cannot be resolved to a type`. What may be causing this? I tried replacing `ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();` with `ClickListener listener = new ClickListener();` and `ActionListener listener = new ActionListener();`, but neither solved the problem. I've included all my code below up until the error line:

```
/**
 * 
 * @author j
 *
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class View extends JPanel implements ItemListener
{
  JCheckBox checkBox1;
  JCheckBox checkBox2;
  JCheckBox checkBox3;
  JCheckBox checkBox4;
  JCheckBox checkBox5;

  JRadioButton radioButton1;
  JRadioButton radioButton2;
  JRadioButton radioButton3;

  JButton submit;

  public View()
  {
    checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Moscow");
    checkBox1.addItemListener(this);

    checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("Saint Petersburg");
    checkBox2.addItemListener(this);

    checkBox3 = new JCheckBox("Novosibirsk");
    checkBox3.addItemListener(this);

    checkBox4 = new JCheckBox("Yekaterinburg");
    checkBox4.addItemListener(this);

    checkBox5 = new JCheckBox("Nizhny Novgorod");
    checkBox5.addItemListener(this);

    radioButton1 = new JRadioButton("5 million");
    radioButton1.addItemListener(this);

    radioButton2 = new JRadioButton("10 million");
    radioButton2.addItemListener(this);

    radioButton3 = new JRadioButton("25 million");
    radioButton3.addItemListener(this);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
    submit.addActionListener(listener);

etc...
```

The error is on the line that states: `ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();`. `ClickListener` is underlined in red.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? Did you actually create such a type?

Comment: @SLaks I guess not, how would I do that? And where would I implement it?

Comment: Then what do you think that line means? You need to learn how classes work.

Comment: @SLaks Sort of, it creates a ClickListener, then assigns the ClickListener to the button so that the button's active state can be monitored.

Comment: But you can't create an instance of a class if you never wrote the class in the first place.